# Github GraphQL API: How can I gather specific user's repositories?

Tags: rest, github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm trying to get repositories of user with login name "somelogin".

It returns all repositories but I'm trying to get repositories owned by him only. Because new API uses GraphQL I couldn't did it.

Currently I'm using:

```json
{
   "query": "query { user(login:\"furknyavuz\") {repositories(first: 50) { nodes { name url }}}}"
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to exclude fork ? use `isFork: false`

Comment: Yes actually I want to exclude all repositories not owned by me.
Can you give me the correct usage of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `isFork: false` to exclude fork. In the [explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) :

```
{
  user(login: "furknyavuz") {
    repositories(first: 50, isFork: false) {
      nodes {
        name
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With curl :

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -d '
 {
   "query": "query { user(login: \"furknyavuz\") { repositories(first: 50, isFork: false) { nodes { name url } } } }"
 }
' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy to build graph QL using the Github GraphQL explorer. Please refer to the attached screenshot.
https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer

{
user(login: "leerob") {
name
email
company
bio
followers {
totalCount
}
following {
totalCount
}
repositories(first: 50, isFork: false) {
nodes {
name
url
stargazerCount
primaryLanguage {
id
name
}
}
}
}
}

[image]